# Doxygen: How to include source files in LaTeX output

Tags: pdf, documentation, latex, doxygen

I'm using doxygen for the documentation of a program and I'm trying to get the actual source files to be included into the PDF-Output of the LaTeX generator.

I've set the following settings in the doxygen configuration file:

```
SOURCE_BROWSER = YES
INLINE_SOURCES = NO
LATEX_SOURCE_CODE = YES
STRIP_CODE_COMMENTS = NO
```

Some tex files containing the sources are being generated, but the generated `refman.pdf` doesn't contain it. When Enabling INLINE_SOURCES, the respective code parts get included though.

So does anyone know how to make doxygen include the actual source code into `refman.pdf` just like it's being included into the html documentation?

**EDIT:**
While the source code isn't included in the PDF, doxygen creates links to the respective page, where the source code should be. However every link links to the nonexistent page 'i'.

**EDIT:**
Same problem still exists with doxygen 1.8.6! I searched through the doxygen archives and found a [post](http://doxygen.10944.n7.nabble.com/Source-browser-doesn-t-work-in-latex-mode-td1696.html#a1697) from 2008 stating, that doxygen can't include source code in the PDF file, but this is probably outdated.

**EDIT:**
I found the corresponding [bugreport](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=436885). I will now start to strip everything from the Doxyfile that is not needed to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Which version of doxygen are you using and which OS

Comment: @albert I'm using doxygen version 1.8.5 on Archlinux with the following Doxyfile: http://pastebin.com/sTfp1GkW

Comment: I've been looking into the problem and with your Doxyfile the problem occurs also on my sources. When using my own Doxyfile the sources are shown. With my own Doxyfile I also noted that when clicking on the line number reference I go to the source code but when clicking on the file name I jump to the beginning of the pdf. an you file a bug report for this problem including your doxyfile and possibly a small dummy source file to reproduce the problem?

Comment: @albert Ok, as soon as I find the time, I'll file a bug report. But I'm not exactly sure, where to do this, the only place I could find that looks like a bugtracker are the archives ( http://doxygen.10944.n7.nabble.com/ ).

Comment: Please have a look at the doxygen documentation, especially: http://www.stack.nl/~dimitri/doxygen/manual/trouble.html#bug_reports here there is a reference to the bugzilla (https://bugzilla.gnome.org/enter_bug.cgi?product=doxygen)

Comment: Been diving into the problem a bit looks like it has to do whether or not the file is included in the documentation or not. In case of HTML the source code is included even when function documentation is not included. When setting \file in a file or globally set EXTRACT_ALL to YES the source code is included in the LaTeX output. The problem of the mentioned bug_436885 originally looks like to be the same problem but has got a different meaning in time, I think now it is about jumping to the beginning of the document (I'll push a fix to bugzilla for this problem).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to albert, the bug should be solved ( I wasn't able to compile it myself, though ) and the fix is already merged upstream.

Albert also provided the workaround to either set `EXTRACT_ALL = YES` or add `\file` for each source file that has to be included.